# Spring MVC controller's handleRequestInternal method doesn't get called - basic example problem

Tags: spring-mvc

I'm a newbie in spring MVC framework. I'm trying to write a simple controller (extends from AbstractController) and want to return a simple view (home.jsp) but seems that the controller's handleRequestInternal() is never called. I'm giving my code below. Any help would be highly appreciated.

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.4"
         xmlns="hiperlink is trimmed "
         xmlns:xsi="hiperlink is trimmed "
         xsi:schemaLocation="hiperlink is trimmed " >

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>students</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>students</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/students/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>


    <filter>
        <filter-name>sitemesh</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.opensymphony.sitemesh.webapp.SiteMeshFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>sitemesh</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <jsp-config>
        <taglib>
            <taglib-uri>/spring</taglib-uri>
            <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/spring-form.tld</taglib-location>
        </taglib>

        <taglib>
            <taglib-uri>hiperlink is trimmed java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core</taglib-uri>
            <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/c.tld</taglib-location>
        </taglib>

        <taglib>
            <taglib-uri>hiperlink is trimmed java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt</taglib-uri>
            <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/fmt.tld</taglib-location>
        </taglib>
    </jsp-config>

</web-app>
```

students-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="hiperlink is trimmed "
       xmlns:xsi="hiperlink is trimmed "       xmlns:context="hiperlink is trimmed" xmlns:jaxws="hiperlink is trimmed "
       xsi:schemaLocation="hiperlink is trimmed ">

      <bean id="handlerMapping"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping"/>

    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="myService" class="net.ochinto.student.service.MiscellaneousService"/>

    <bean name="/home.htm" class="net.ochinto.student.web.HomePageController">
        <property name="myService" ref="myService"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

HomePageController.java

```
public class HomePageController extends AbstractController {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HomePageController.class);

    public HomePageController() {
        log.debug("HomePageController constructor()");
    }

    protected ModelAndView handleRequestInternal(
            HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws Exception {

        log.debug("HomePageController handleRequestInternal()");

        List<Student> students = myService.getStudentList();
        return new ModelAndView("home", "students", students);
    }

    private MiscellaneousService myService;

    public void setMyService(MiscellaneousService myService) {
        log.debug("HomePageController setMyService() - start");
        this.myService = myService;
        log.debug("HomePageController setMyService() - end");
    }
}
```

welcome page is ok but when I write /students/home.htm 404 is returned! Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You say:

> welcome page is ok but when I write /students/home.htm 404 is returned! Please help.

Your configuration only has one URL mapping, the one for /home.htm. You need to add additional mappings if you want /students/home.htm to point some where.

Check out the [Handler Mapping](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/mvc.html#mvc-handlermapping) section of the Spring docs for more info.

Comment: I noticed that if in the web.xml I use *.htm for the url-pattern then it works. I did not read the handler mapping completely but I would assume all the answers to be there. Thanks for pointing to that topic.